# Getting common commands count from log file on MacOS

Tags: macos, shell, unix

I need to get info from system on how many times I've entered "pw" "ls" and "cd" commands.

```
#!/bin/bash 
#HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
#set -o history
echo "Printing number of ls commands used" > LogFile
a='history | grep -w "ls" | wc -1'
echo $a >> LogFile
echo "Printing number of cd commands used" >> LogFile
b='history | grep -w "cd" | wc -1'
echo $b >> LogFile
echo "Printing number of pwd commands used" >> LogFile
b='history | grep -w "pwd" | wc -1'
echo $c >> LogFile

cat LogFile
```

and my output on terminal:

```
Joyces-MacBook-Pro:desktop Joyce$ ./failedlogin_detect.sh
Printing number of ls commands used
history | grep -w "ls" | wc -1
Printing number of cd commands used
history | grep -w "cd" | wc -1
Printing number of pwd commands used
```

The sentences print fine, but it's not retrieving the count from the system.

Comment: Try a=$(history | grep -w "ls" | wc -1), or at least back tick.

Comment: Using the wrong character.  Need to use a back tick. Not a single quote.

Comment: Thank you for your swift response. I'm getting "wc: illegal option -- 1 
usage: wc [-clmw] [file ...]

Comment: Shouldn't that be : wc -l (lowercase L) instead of wc -1 (number one) ? Sorry, didn't noticed it the first time

Comment: @AndreGelinas you're a genius! <3

Comment: I don't see how `echo "Printing number of ls commands used" > LogFile` can produce "my output on terminal"? Try `cat LogFile` to see what has been saved there. But yes, you main problem is `a=$(hist....)` . Join the 90s and use the `$(...)` form on command substitution (not backticks). And, sorry to beat up on you, your code does not match the functionality described in your script name, `./failedlogin_detect.sh`, I'll assume that is your final goal, and you're just trying to get anything to work ;-) (I know that feeling!). Good luck.

Comment: a=$(history | grep -w "ls" | wc -l) worked fine for me... and yes, this is just 1/3 of the whole project, so goddamn happy when something works.